# Segmentation fault when attempting to copy an address into a struct?

Tags: linux, assembly, nasm, x86-64

I have a NASM program that is crashing with a segmentation fault.

At the beginning of the file, the following struct is defined:

```
struc mystruct
    .myhandler resq 1
endstruc
```

An instance of the struct is created in the `.bss` section:

```
section .bss

    inst resb mystruct
```

The first thing the program does is attempt to store the address of a label in the struct's only field:

```
section .text
global _start

_start:

    lea rax, [handler]
    mov [inst + mystruct.myhandler], rax

handler:

    ; ...
```

According to GDB, the `lea` and `mov` instructions are as follows:

```
(gdb) disassemble _start
Dump of assembler code for function _start:
=> 0x0000000000400080 <+0>: lea    rax,ds:0x400090
   0x0000000000400088 <+8>: mov    QWORD PTR ds:0x601000,rax
...
```

However, running the application results in a segmentation fault:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000400088 in _start ()
```

Why is this?

---

**Edit:** additional information:

```
$ nm -S app.o
0000000000000010 t handler
0000000000000000 b inst
0000000000000000 a mystruct
0000000000000000 a mystruct.myhandler
0000000000000008 a mystruct_size
0000000000000000 T _start

$ size -A app.o
app.o  :
section   size   addr
.text     16      0
.bss       0      0
Total     16
```

Comment: Can you tell me the output of `nm -S object.o` where `object.o` is the object file containing `inst`?

Comment: Also, `size -A object.o` might be useful as well.

Comment: @fuz I have added the information.

Comment: BTW, NASM's default setting is absolute addressing, not RIP-relative.  `DEFAULT REL` will use the more compact RIP-relative addressing.  (The only reason you'd use `lea` instead of `mov eax, handler` is for position-independent code.  Or `mov [inst + mystruct.myhandler], handler`)

Comment: It looks like `inst resb mystruct` is reserving 0 bytes in the BSS, so your process doesn't have a BSS at all (you could check `/proc/PID/maps` or `smaps`).  But it still assembles and links somehow.  I don't know what the right syntax is for `sizeof()` in NASM; I never use its struct syntax.

Comment: I am not super familiar with nasm, but it appears that instead of `inst resb mystruct` you might need `inst resb mystruct_size`.

Comment: @PeterCordes aha! That was the problem indeed.

Comment: Also, don't forget to `exit_group` your process before falling through into `handler`, if that's not intended.  (`mov eax, 231` / `syscall`).  See also the [x86 tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info) for lots more links to docs / reference material / performance info.

Comment: @PeterCordes correct - I'm not using libc, so I will add a syscall to `sys_exit` at the end. I just wanted the question to focus on the part that was crashing.

Comment: That's almost exactly what I was suggesting :).  `__NR_exit_group` is 231, the same system call that libc's `_exit()` uses.  It's equivalent to `sys_exit` (eax=60) for single-threaded processes, but I usually use `231` even though it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Peter Cordes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/224132/peter-cordes) noted in a comment that:

> It looks like inst resb mystruct is reserving 0 bytes in the BSS, so your process doesn't have a BSS at all. But it still assembles and links somehow. I don't know what the right syntax is for sizeof() in NASM; I never use its struct syntax.

It turns out that what I needed to do was change:

```
act resb mystruct
```

...to...

```
act resb mystruct_size
```

This symbol is automatically defined by the assembler and is set to the size of the struct in bytes.

The program no longer crashes on that section of code.